# how to print in terminal a directory tree of spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

I would like to print my spring project directory tree, likely in intellij idea. 
Is there any maven or spring boot commands to print the tree using internal IDE terminal? 
Maybe other quick commands to print it?
A desired result should be like this:

```
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── hello
```

Didn't find anything quick in maven or spring boot commands, except linux apt tree

Comment: Did you try `tree` in bash?

Comment: Why would you like to do that via plugin? Spring Boot is a framework or spring-boot Maven plugin? What would the purpose of this?

Comment: @khmarbaise I would like to know if there are any commands in spring-boot or maven to print the tree.

Comment: @khmarbaise Just as a matter of curiosity

Comment: Ok..No there is no such plugin nor in Maven nor from Spring-boot-maven-plugin (Not that I know off).